# Nlog get Azure Blob Storage connection string from Appsettings

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, nlog

I'm working on my first .Net Core website in Azure and I'm using NLog along with blob storage. I've got that working but the connection string is hard coded in the NLog.config file right now. I would like to move the connection string into the appsettings.json file so that I can change it for either Dev/Stage environments based on where I'm publishing it to in my CI/CD pipeline. I found the following article that uses Azure Key Vault for the connection string and eventually we will start using Key Vault but we are not at that point just yet. The function that I need to use is the UpdateNLogConfig in the article where I'll pull the connection from appsettings.json and then set it to the GDC which I will then retrieve from the NLog.config file. What I'm not sure is when/where do I call the UpdateNLogConfig.

https://www.taithienbo.com/securely-log-to-blob-storage-using-nlog-with-connection-string-in-key-vault/

This is what I have in my Program.cs so far. I know I'll need to add the `UpdateNLogConfig()` here as well.

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //var logger = NLog.Web.NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
            try
            {
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                //logger.Error(exception, "Stopped program because of exception.");
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                // Ensure to flush and stop internal timers/threads before application-exit (Avoid segmentation fault on Linux)
                NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
            }
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
              .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
              {
                  webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
              })
              .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
              {
                  logging.ClearProviders();
                  logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
              })
              .UseNLog();  
    }
```

UPDATE:

I'm working on converting over to setting the NLog configuration in my `appsettings.json` instead of using `NLog.config` file. I have followed the threads suggested and came up with the following. It will write out to the `internal-nlog.txt` file but I can't get it to create or write out to my LocalTarget. I feel like it must be installed and configured because it's writing to the internal-nlog.txt but I can's see what would be causing it to not write to my LocalTarget.

Program.cs

```
 public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
              .SetBasePath(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
              .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true).Build();
            NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration nlogConfig = new NLogLoggingConfiguration(config.GetSection("NLog"));

            var logger = NLog.Web.NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog(LogManager.Configuration).GetCurrentClassLogger();
            try
            {
                logger.Debug("Initialize main");

                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error(ex, "Stopped program because of exception.");
                //throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
            }
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
              .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
              {
                  webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
              })
              .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
              {
                  logging.ClearProviders();
                  logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
              })
              .UseNLog();  // NLog: Setup NLog for Dependency injection
    }
```

appsettings.json

```
  "NLog": {
    "internalLogLevel": "Info",
    "internalLogFile": "c:\\temp\\NLog\\internal-nlog.txt",
    "extensions": {
      "NLog.Web.AspNetCore": {
        "assembly": "NLog.Web.AspNetCore"
      }
    },
    "targets": {
      "LocalTarget": {
        "type": "File",
        "fileName": "c:\\temp\\NLog\\PayDocs_${shortdate}.log",
        "layout": "${longdate} | ${uppercase:${level}} | ${callsite} | ${message}"
    },
    "rules": [
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "Trace",
        "writeTo": "LocalTarget"
      },
      {
        "logger": "Microsoft.*",
        "maxLevel": "Info",
        "final": "true"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: If you need further help, pls let me know.

Comment: You can load configuration-values from host-configuration (ex. from appsettings.json) using `${configsetting}`. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ConfigSetting-Layout-Renderer You can then override config-setting with values from Azure Key Value using `AddAzureKeyVault` See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration

Comment: See also the docs for loading connection-string: https://github.com/JDetmar/NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage/blob/master/src/NLog.Extensions.AzureBlobStorage/README.md#azure-connectionstring

Comment: Added an updated to the original post. I'm must be missing something in the settings to get it to write my file target.

Comment: @Caverman Just like with xml-file, then json-file has to be valid format. Notice missing ending-curly-brace that matches `"targets: {`. Notice that `${configsetting}` also works fine when used in `NLog.config` and can load connectionstring from `appsettings.json`.

Comment: @RolfKristensen thanks for catching the missing } from my targets section. Unfortunate for me is it didn't make a difference. It's still not writing out to my targets. Not sure if you have another suggestion. Also, not completely understanding your second statement with NLog.config but I will say I'm trying to put my NLog settings in my appsettings so that I can change out things like the BlobStorage key when I use CI/CD pipeline to push my code to Azure. I could probably setup the same for the NLog.config but I already have it setup for appsettings if I can get it to work.

Comment: @Caverman Think you have diverted from your original question. Maybe start a new question? Have you considered starting with a simple example and work from there?  https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-configuration-with-appsettings.json#simple-json-nlog-config-example Also notice the guide for troubleshooting NLog-issues is still here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UpdateNLogConfig` just load nlog configuration, and it's a custom method.

You can load your configuration from `appsettings.json` by below code.

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true).Build();
NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration nlogConfig = new NLogLoggingConfiguration(config.GetSection("NLog"));
```

*For more details, you can refer below related post. *

[How can I configure NLog in .NET Core with appsettings.json instead of an nlog.config file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56246416/how-can-i-configure-nlog-in-net-core-with-appsettings-json-instead-of-an-nlog-c)

Comment: Good idea. I forgot about calling NLog settings from the appsettings file instead of NLog.config. I'm going to try to work on changing that up in my site this afternoon. I'll let you know how it goes.